# How should I cope with the clash between the package "xeCJK" and "mathspec"?

Tags: xetex, option-clash

I wanted to configure math fonts in my document, and tried with `mathspec`, only to find it clashed with `fontspec`. For I have to use Chinese in my document, I have to load `xeCJK` package which automatically loads `fontspec`. How could I avoid such a clash?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}   % Using XeLaTeX
\usepackage{mathspec}  % Clash!

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `mathspec` and `xeCJK` both load `fontspec` but while `xeCJK` loads it without any options, `mathspec` by default loads `fontspec` with the `no-math` option.  That is an option clash.

To work around this you have to pass the `no-math` option also when loading `fontspec` the first time within `xeCJK`.  This can be done by means of `\PassOptionsToPackage`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```